# How to increase the Time Out of Rest-Assured API call

Tags: rest-assured

Issue is I make the call and The error come back with 'Connection Timed Out'.  how to increase the time out?
 
Here is my code:

RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

Response response = request.get("https://unicef-registry.sdmxcloud.org/ws/public/sdmxapi/rest/data/UNICEF,CME_DF,1.0/.TMM0..269.?format=sdmx-json&includeHistory=true&includeMetadata=true&dimensionAtObservation=AllDimensions&includeAllAnnotations=true");

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(5000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                .setSocketTimeout(5000).build();

        HttpClientConfig httpClientFactory = HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                .httpClientFactory(() -> HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build());

        RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().httpClient(httpClientFactory);
```

Comment: if it works, please mark the answer so that others  can also make use of it [ for me too in the future]. thnx